# How can I detect the edges of this image?

Tags: opencv, edge-detection

I want to find the square edges of this image with OpenCV.

[image: this image]

I tried to find edges with Canny, Laplacian, and Sobel, but square border detection is not succeeding.

Comment: You cannot detect  the square using edge detection only . you'll need to use edge detection result and build an algorithm.

Comment: Are you trying to break a captcha ? IMO the digits are much easier to find than the squares.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Steps to detect Squares :

1) - Apply edge detection  canny , sobel , prewitt ..etc

2) - Apply probabilistic hough transform or LSD (line segment detector)

3) Filter out the bigger   segments and keep small once based on threshold.

4 ) gather remaining segments based on collinearity.

5 ) construct rectangles based on intesections.

*(6) Skip all and use deep learning segmentation.